# Are there any valid stats showing cost benefits of working in PHP compared to .NET?

Tags: php, .net

It's a bit of a leading question, I know, but this question came up in a PHP Users group discussion and I was interested to see if there were any studies done comparing the two (regardless of who "wins").

I can see there are many tangibles to compare in licensing, IDEs, hosting, etc., as well as the intangibles of amount of time spent on tasks and so on.

It is also quite possible that this question has no merit and can't be answered...?

Comment: You might as well ask if there are cost benefits to speaking German in the office, versus Spanish.

Comment: Why leave this as a comment? I think it's a perfectly valid answer to this question.. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't really make any sense considering you seem to be asking from the developer's standpoint

But for the heck of it here are some salary stats:
http://www.indeed.com/salary?q1=.Net+Developer&l1=&q2=PHP+Developer&l2=

Also to build a PHP server the only costs would be the hardware, while on a windows server there would probably be licensing fees.

Comment: In a large project you would tend to expect the licensing costs (however huge for big server licenses) to be pretty small compared to the costs of people. Your "extortionate" $20k license might be 20% of the cost of _one_ developer's salary.